# Elasticsearch Connection

Tags: python, elasticsearch, ssl, ssl-certificate, kibana

I am using
python:2.7.16
Elasticsearch:6.8.12 with TLS enable

I am getting output on my server/host
if i run
curl --insecure $CREDS -X GET "localhost:9210/metricbeat*/_search" | python -m json.tool

if I use below code in my python script:

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

url = Elasticsearch(['https://' + options.controller + ':9210/metricbeat*/_search'], verify_certs=False, connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)

Error:
collecting system information...
/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py:141: UserWarning: Connecting to https://x.x.x.x:9210 using SSL with verify_certs=False is insecure.
% self.host
waiting for query results...
error: failed to query elastic search data: No connection adapters were found for u"<Elasticsearch([{u'url_prefix': '/metricbeat*/_search', u'use_ssl': True, u'host': 'x.x.x.x', u'port': 9210}])>"

[option.controller is my server/host]

Any help would be appreciated,Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something in your url is wrong and it cannot recognize to send the request. Try printing the exact url you are requesting before sending, maybe you can detect the error there.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use the API wrong.   your URL should have the same path as your curl request the resulting object should have a search() method to do the search and you pass parameters into that to do the search.

Comment: I am getting output if i run
curl --insecure $CREDS -X GET "https://localhost:9210/metricbeat*/_search" | python -m json.tool

but not getting through url which is in my python script

Comment: So  when you are constructing the ElasticSearch object with the Elasticsearch() method.  You need to only provide the base url info.  Do not include the path /metricbeat*/_search

then call the method search() with the right parameters to do the search and get back results.

Answer (score 0):

You want something more like the following:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

es = Elasticsearch(hosts=['https://' + options.controller + ':9210'],
                   verify_certs=False, 
                   connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)
result = elastic_client.search(index="metricbeat*", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
```